# nginx reverse proxy an apache2 website : url return are not corresponding to proxy server

Tags: nginx, apache2, url-routing, reverse-proxy

I am looking for some tips how to do what I wanna do currently.

Here is what I am suppose to do :
Nginx server proxy (srvrp) -> Apache2 (srvdeba)

Here is the config of nginx website srvrp :

```
server {
        server_name www.egloff-j-quest-etna.nx;

        location / {
                 proxy_pass http://srvdeba.egloff-j-quest-etna.nx;
                 proxy_redirect off;
                 proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                 proxy_set_header Host $proxy_host;
                 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                 proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        }
}
```

Here is the config of the srvdeba site-enabled website :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName www.srvdeba.egloff-j-quest-etna.nx
    ServerAlias *srvdeba.egloff-j-quest-etna.nx

    DocumentRoot /opt/wordpress
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /opt/wordpress/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Currently, this is working, but not totally, the problem is the following :
When the website is loaded through the proxy, all links on the website are on this form :
    http://srvdeba.egloff-j-quest-etna.nx
I want them to correspond to :
    www.egloff-j-quest-etna.nx

So, I have come up with 2 solutions, the first one would be to use ngx_http_sub_module
and the second one would be to configure apache2 so he knows he is being proxied and can rewrite URLs when the request has been done through the proxy server.
srvdeba has to work when being accessed without the proxy server.
So I need you to tell me what would be the best solution for this !

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Well, I tried the ngx_http_sub_module, and it wasn't working at all. Maybe I did something wrong about it though. Now I'll try to configure apache2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I finally found an answer to this problem a long time ago.
I think it's best that I share it to you.

The problem is not coming from apache nor nginx.
The problem is coming from the website generating wrong urls cause he doesn't know he is being proxied.
So, if you have similar problems, you should make sure the website knows he is being proxied and generate correct URLs to work for the client request.